# We are unable to find animation of exported object as Collada (.dea) if animation is a modifier animation while using Blender 2.82

Tags: animation, export, collada

We exported an object with an animation as "dea" and imported in other application to use.
Object's animation was movement animation.
It worked great.

Then we changed animation type and made a modifier animation like surface subdivision.
It worked in Blender.
But when we exported the object exactly the same way with previous one.

There seems to be no animation in imported application.
In previous one we could find name of the animation Blender gave but at modifier animation 
we even could not find the name of the animation.

There must be something we skip, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the type you are exporting it. Collada(.dae) is used for exporting objects or meshes not armature action you should use the export type bvh motion capture, this allows you to export armature action with the object.